# mov vs xchg in spin lock implementatoin

Tags: assembly, x86, spinlock

I'm reading through this [online book on x86](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/X86_Assembly/Data_Transfer#Application) and I'm curious about an implementation detail in their example code for implementing a spin lock. In the example, they use a `xchg` to set a memory location to 0 rather than a `mov` and I'm trying to understand why that choice was made.

In the spin lock example there is a function, `spinUnlock` which puts a `0` in the memory location `[sLock]`.  `[sLock]` is set to `0` if the lock is free and `1` when it is aquired.  The `spinUnlock` function sets `[sLock]` to `0` freeing the lock.  The code follows:

```
spinUnlock:
    push    ebp
    mov ebp, esp
    mov eax, 0
    xchg    eax, [sLock]
    pop ebp
    ret
```

Why use `mov eax, 0; xchg eax, [sLock]` to set `[sLock]` to `0` rather than `mov [sLock], 0`? The `eax` register is not used for anything after the calls to `spinUnlock`. I know that `xchg` will lock the memory location, but if `mov` is already atomic then a lock is unnecessary.

Comment: `mov` is atomic but does not impose a memory ordering.  `xchg` does the latter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Only the author can say why the choice was made.

A single `mov dword [sLock],0` would work fine; and an `xchg eax, [sLock]` (which has an implied `lock`) is likely to be more expensive (for both performance and code size).

All of the example's code is awful (e.g. no `pause` in the `spinLock` routine where it should be used despite having `pause` in places where it shouldn't be used at all); and their choice of example isn't good either.

*Note: using spinlocks in user-space is "almost never" sane because the OS may do a task switch after you acquire a lock but before you release it, causing all other tasks to waste a massive amount of CPU time spinning with no hope of acquiring the lock.*

Comment: `xchg` is used because it implies a memory barrier.  This is actually recommended if you want a store with memory barrier semantics.

Comment: @fuz: Sure; but you don't want that for the example code (store forwarding won't be a problem due to `lock` being used in any future attempt to re-acquire, so "relatively strong ordering" is enough to avoid a barrier).

Comment: "All of the example's code is awful": this is good to know. I may be better off finding a different source rather than continue with this book.